# Clear all selected values from material-ui Autocomplete Combo box

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

**Solution**

I used `renderTags` in my `Autocomplete`:

```
renderTags={() => (
    <div>
        {(props.selectedAutocompleteValues).map(value => (
            <Chip key={value} label={value} />
        ))}
    </div>
)}
```

**Original question**

I'm trying to add a handler that clears all selected values from an Autocomplete with multiple values and a dropdown. Basicly duplicating the action of the clear-button that is inside the Autocomplete, and triggering this action from outside the Autocomplete.

The reason for this is that I want to have a filter (material-ui Select) that allows reduces the number of options in the Autocomplete. When changing the filter-value, the previously selected values of the Autocomplete should be cleared.

I'm rendering the values in the Autocomplete with the following code, so it seems like what I need to do is change the `params` in some way. Any suggestions on how to do this, or other ways of clearing the values?

```
renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} label="my-label" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
)}
```

**Update after comment from Ryan Cogswell**:

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    disableCloseOnSelect
    autoHighlight
    clearText='Nullstill'
    closeText='Lukk'
    openText='Åpne'
    options={Array.from(props.myMap.keys())}
    onChange={(event: any, value: string) => {
        props.myUpdateFunction(value)
    }}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="myLabel" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
    )}
/>
```

where `myUpdateFunction` is in the grandparent-component of where the `Autocomplete is`:

```
myUpdateFunction = (myArray: Array<string>) => {
    this.setState({
        selectedAutocompleteValues: myArray,
    })
}
```

The `Select` component that I want to use to reset the `Autocomplete` component:

```
<Select
    labelId="my-select-label"
    id="my-select"
    autoWidth
    value={props.mySelectValue}
    onChange={(event: any) => props.updateSelect(event.target.value)}>
    {Array.from(props.selectOptions, ([optionNr, optionName]) =>
        <MenuItem key={optionNr} value={optionNr}>{optionName}</MenuItem>
    )}
</Select>
```

with the following onChange handler:

```
updateFylke = (value: number) => {
    const selectedAutocompleteValues = new Array<string>();
    this.setState({
        mySelectValue: value,
        selectedAutocompleteValues: selectedAutocompleteValues,
    })
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire code of your `Autocomplete` component and any related code you are using to manage its state.

Comment: I have added an update now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) approach (i.e. specify the `value` prop for the `Autocomplete` using `selectedAutocompleteValues`). Then clearing the `Autocomplete` is just a matter of updating your state appropriately.

You can see an example of this approach in this related answer: [Material ui Autocomplete: can tags be created on events aside from 'Enter' events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035788/material-ui-autocomplete-can-tags-be-created-on-events-aside-from-enter-event/59038435#59038435).