# Capturing Tab Key on Material UI AutoComplete Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sea-h2i0m

Here's the code for the Autocomplete from that sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { FieldProps } from "formik";

const isEmailValid = (email: string) =>
  /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);

const EmailsField = ({
  field,
  form: { errors, touched, setTouched, setFieldValue },
  ...props
}: FieldProps) => {
  const name = field.name;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, emails: string[]) => {
    setTouched({ ...touched, [name]: true });
    setValue(emails);
    event.persist();
    setFieldValue(name, emails);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
    newInputValue: string
  ) => {
    const options = newInputValue.split(/[ ,]+/);
    const fieldValue = value
      .concat(options)
      .map(x => x.trim())
      .filter(x => x);

    if (options.length > 1) {
      handleChange(event, fieldValue);
    } else {
      setInputValue(newInputValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete<string>
      multiple
      disableClearable={true}
      options={[]}
      freeSolo
      renderTags={(emails, getTagProps) =>
        emails.map((email, index) => (
          <Chip
            deleteIcon={<CloseIcon />}
            variant="default"
            label={email}
            color={isEmailValid(email) ? "primary" : "secondary"}
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
          />
        ))
      }
      value={value}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          name={name}
          error={touched[name] && Boolean(errors.emails)}
          helperText={touched[name] && errors.emails}
          variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps }}
          {...props}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default EmailsField;
```

I'm unable to make the value typed by the user become a single option after the user types and then presses the tab  keyboard button to move to the submit button.

Any idea how?

Comment: You have a multiple auto complete. Do you want to create a new option if you tab without using enter because unless you do it doesn't make sense for the autocomplete to hold the value

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/lab`: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-vtozu.

Comment: Precisely, that's what I want!

Comment: @RyanCogswell thank you but that changes nothing, or am I missing something?

Comment: Tab no longer causes the value to disappear after the upgrade.

Comment: Right; I'm sorry my question wasn't clear, I just edited it. I want the tab to generate an option from the text that was entered actually. It makes sense that if the user enters a single email address there and click on tab that it doesn't require them to press the enter or the space key.

Answer (score 12):

You can accomplish this by adding a handler for `onKeyDown`:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Tab": {
        if (inputValue.length > 0) {
          handleChange(event, value.concat([inputValue]));
        }
        break;
      }
      default:
    }
  };
```

and then adding that to the text input via `inputProps`:

```
      renderInput={params => {
        params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            name={name}
            error={touched[name] && Boolean(errors.emails)}
            helperText={touched[name] && errors.emails}
            variant="outlined"
            {...props}
          />
        );
      }}
```

Here's the full new code for the `EmailsField` component from your sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { FieldProps } from "formik";

const isEmailValid = (email: string) =>
  /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);

const EmailsField = ({
  field,
  form: { errors, touched, setTouched, setFieldValue },
  ...props
}: FieldProps) => {
  const name = field.name;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, emails: string[]) => {
    setTouched({ ...touched, [name]: true });
    setValue(emails);
    event.persist();
    setFieldValue(name, emails);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
    newInputValue: string
  ) => {
    const options = newInputValue.split(/[ ,]+/);
    const fieldValue = value
      .concat(options)
      .map(x => x.trim())
      .filter(x => x);

    if (options.length > 1) {
      handleChange(event, fieldValue);
    } else {
      setInputValue(newInputValue);
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Tab": {
        if (inputValue.length > 0) {
          handleChange(event, value.concat([inputValue]));
        }
        break;
      }
      default:
    }
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete<string>
      multiple
      disableClearable={true}
      options={[]}
      freeSolo
      renderTags={(emails, getTagProps) =>
        emails.map((email, index) => (
          <Chip
            deleteIcon={<CloseIcon />}
            variant="default"
            label={email}
            color={isEmailValid(email) ? "primary" : "secondary"}
            {...getTagProps({ index })}
          />
        ))
      }
      value={value}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      renderInput={params => {
        params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            name={name}
            error={touched[name] && Boolean(errors.emails)}
            helperText={touched[name] && errors.emails}
            variant="outlined"
            {...props}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default EmailsField;
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete]

Related answer: [Material ui Autocomplete: can tags be created on events aside from 'Enter' events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035788/material-ui-autocomplete-can-tags-be-created-on-events-aside-from-enter-event/59038435#59038435)

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward solution with recent mui version is to use `onKeyDown` attribute:

```
<Autocomplete
    ...
    onKeyDown={(event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Tab') {
            event.key = 'Enter'; // will call `onChange`
        }
    }}
    ...

/>
```