# How to Disable the ENTER Key in React Material UI Autocomplete form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a Material UI Autocomplete form in a React component. It works perfect, except the ENTER key is currently clearing the input field. *I simply want the input field to **not** be cleared when the user hits ENTER key*. I searched through all the similar questions on Stackoverflow, and none of them deal with ignoring this key inside of an Autocomplete form (they mostly deal with regular input forms).  Below I list all the things I have tried that don't work.

How can I disable the ENTER key in this situation??

I have tried ignoring the enter key such as :

```js
onKeyPress={(event) => {return event.key !== 'Enter';}}
```

I have also tried stopping the autocomplete enter key from being taken as a form submit (hoping it wouldn't clear the form) by doing this:

```js
onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
}
```

I even tried :

```js
onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
}
```

And, yes, I also tried using `onKeyDown` instead `onKeyPress` for both the above examples.

Finally, I tried using the `disableClearable` option in the Autocomplete component as below:

```js
  const onInputChange = useCallback(
    (_event: ChangeEvent<{}>, newInputValue: string) => {
      debounceFetchData(newInputValue);
    },
    [debounceFetchData]
  );

  return (
    <section className={classes.container}>
      <SearchIcon className={classes.icon} />
      <Autocomplete
        id="search"
        options={options}
        disableClearable
        getOptionLabel={() => ''}
        filterOptions={(x) => x}
        fullWidth
        freeSolo
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder="Search"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              'aria-label': 'Search',
            }}
          />
        )}
        ...
        ...
        ...
      />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had stuck on this for some time as well and found the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035788/material-ui-autocomplete-can-tags-be-created-on-events-aside-from-enter-event).

Simply it can be handled by passing `onKeyDown` handler to `inputProps` of `<TextField>` :

```js
 <Autocomplete
        ...
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            ...
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              onKeyDown: (e) => {
                    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        ...
        ...
        ...
      />
```

Comment: Don't forget to spread the `...params.inputProps` before `onKeyDown` handler

Answer (score 2):

This works, but it removes the ability to use the keyboard to select a value.

Note that the ellipses after `{...params}` should be omitted.

Comment: that `...` and others ones (after `<Autocomplete`, and near the end before`/>`) are all just markers indicating "more code goes here". They are not meant to be part of the code itself..

Comment: You should use the `autoHighlight` prop if you'd like to still be able to use Enter to select values.

This will however clear the input as it selects a value.