# Material UI Autocomplete freeSolo - Disable enter to close select box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

As one can try out [in the official docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#search-input), typing in a letter that exists in the options (e.g. "t") and pressing enter closes the whole select box. It depends on the MUI Autocomplete being in freeSolo mode.

I tried to record it. Obviously you have to assume I pressed enter when the select box closes:

[image: select box close on enter]

I'd like to disable this behavior. The select box should stay open when one presses enter while the input is focused. I am aware of the fact that I can completely disable enter events like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887764/3608380) and [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#events), but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71485641/3608380) stated, this completely removes the ability to use the enter key to select a value.

I tried to detect differences in the event whether is was beeing fired by enter-ing the search input vs enter-ing one of the options, but they seem identical. (target is always the input).

Any ideas on how to solve this?